Subtasks doubling when a new task is added
I'm creating a To-Do application. You can enter many options in the form, but I am interested in subtasks. Subtasks in the form are added in the input by pressing Enter. I want to store these subtasks for a specific task and when I hover over a later added task, I want to display its subtasks.
Code


    const confirmTaskBtn = document.querySelector(".confirm-task-btn");
    confirmTaskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let title = document.querySelector(".titleInput").value;

            tasksDiv.innerHTML += 
            `    
            <div class="task">
                        <div class="subtasks">
                            <div class="list-quantity">${subtasks.length}</div> Subtasks
                            <div class="subtasks-list-hover"></div>
                        </div>
            </div>
            `

            const subtaskList = document.querySelector(".subtasks-list-hover");
            showSubtask(subtaskList, subtasks);

            showSubtask();
        }
    })

let subtasks = [];
const subtaskInput = document.querySelector(".add-subtask-input");

subtaskInput.addEventListener("keyup", (ev) => {
    if (ev.key === "Enter") {
        const subtask = subtaskInput.value;
        let subtaskList = document.querySelector(".subtasks-list ul");
        subtaskList.innerHTML += `<li>${subtask}</li>`;
        subtasks.push(subtask);
        subtaskInput.value = "";
    }
});

const showSubtask = (subtaskList, subtasks) => {
    subtaskList.innerHTML = subtasks.map(subtask => `<p>${subtask}</p>`).join("");
};
            <div class="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Title" class="titleInput">
                <p class="titleErr">Musisz coś wpisać!</p>

                <div class="subtasks">
                    <h2>Subtasks:</h2>
                    <div class="add-subtask"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> <input type="text" placeholder="Add New Subtask" class="add-subtask-input"></div>
                    <div class="subtasks-list">
                        <ul></ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="buttons">
                    <button class="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="confirm-task-btn">Confirm</button>
                </div>
            </div>




The problem is that the data doubles when you hover over the task.
